# How do I modify a script via HTML in a Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, cewp

I can add a script or CSS in a webpart via the broswer
CEWP > HTML

But how do I do the same , what more modify a CEWP with script in it when I am in SPD 2010? I can't seem to figure it out nor can see the script in the CEWP because there id not HTML ribbon button.

Comment: you can add html & script in file. Then link it with your **CEWP**

Comment: I don't understand :(  - In SharePoint Designer how to see/edit the script in a CEWP?

Comment: writing details in answer

Comment: did my explanation make sense to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way, you are trying it does not sound good. You can try it in the following way.

1. Add your css in separate file like `myStyle.css`
2. Add your script in separate file like `myScript.js`
3. Now create a text file like `myCEWP.txt`

Upload all the files in a assets library like **Site Assets**

Now open the text file and add css, js reference and also add other html.

```
<link href="/Site Assets/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/SiteAssets/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div >
    <!-- Write other html code here -->
</div>
```

Now link this `myCEWP.txt` file with your **CEWP** from browser.

[image]

**Update:** If you need this `myCEWP.txt` file under **SharePoint Source Control**, see the first comment by DannyEngelman. I found a problem in Standard version 6 months back. May be it is not there now.

Comment: name it ``CEWP.html`` instead of ``CEWP.tx`` then you can open the file in Designer. Note: **This file will be under SharePoint source control... **so if you rename ``myStyle.js`` to something else.. SharePoint will rename the link inside ``CEWP.html`` for you.. **SharePoint IS Cool!**

Comment: I am familiar with  **SharePoint source control**. I found a problem in Standard version 6 months back that html does not render properly if I use `.html`. May be it is not there now. `.tx` was a typo. I meant `.txt`. Your comments/answers are also cool. I appreciate it always.